# Can someone help me with a simple perl script

Tags: perl

I have a perl script that professor gave which is suppose to be easy to run, but my machine is giving error, which i don't understand.
since the directory this file is in has another file named file_in which i created because i think that's the only thing i need to do in order to run this script. But it's giving me an error at line 33. Please help me .
Thank you,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# the strict package forces you to declare each variable you use beforehand
use strict;

# a variable in strict mode is declared using my
# the $ symbol means it is a single-valued variable
# the @ symbol means it is an array
# each declaration/instruction is closed with a ; sign 
my @par_list = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

# creating a variable for the current value of the parameter
my $value;

# get and store the size of the array
my $nbr_of_values = $#par_list;

# now, we read in a variable that will be the filename of the template input file
# $ARGV are the input arguments, 0 means it is the first one (perl starts counting at 0, not 1)
my $file_in = $ARGV[0];

# start of the loop
for( my $i=0; $i<= $nbr_of_values; $i++){
    $value = $par_list[$i];
    print "This is the current parameter value: $value \n";

    # now we create a new string variable that will later be the filename of the new input deck
    # the . symbol is the concatenation operator between strings
    my $new_input_filename = $file_in."_".$value;
    print " The new filename is $new_input_filename \n";

    # open the template file and store its filehandle (fh_in)
    open my $fh_in,  '<', $file_in or die "Can't open output $file_in !";
    # open the new file (it currently does not exist and is thus empty) and store its filehandle (fh_out)
    open my $fh_out, '>', $new_input_filename or die "Can't open output $new_input_filename !";

    while (<$fh_in>) {
    # this is for you to see on the console, we read line-by-line, while there is something
    # the line read is stored in a special PERL variable $_
    print "I have read $_";
    # now we actually print that line intot he new file
    print $fh_out $_;
    }
    close $fh_in; 
    close fh_out;
}

print " I am done with this !!! \n";
exit 111;
```

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting?  That error message probably has vital clues as to what the problem is.

Comment: Just a few other items.  It might be helpful to "use warnings;" on the line after "use strict;", which could help provide useful warnings.  The variable $nbr_of_values really isn't getting the size of the array as the comments suggest.  Instead, it's getting the last element ID of the array.  Also, it looks like line 33 corresponds with the first open statement.  If you could the variable $! inside the double quotes after the word die, then you would get an error message giving some information on why Perl was unable to open a file.

Comment: Do you have the 10 files that your script is supposed to be reading? Is the error message that you're exiting with an exit code of 111?

Comment: It's suppose to make 10 files.

Comment: error msg: can't open output ! at perl_part3.pl line 33

Comment: @J.Doe You don't understand the script. It's not supposed to create 10 files, it's supposed to **copy** 10 files. And the files to be copied are to have the format `filename_X`, where `filename` is provided when you run the script, and `X` is a number, from 1 to 10. The `$fh_in` is the file handle to read the file, and copy the contents to another file with the file handle `$fh_out`.

Comment: Check the file which you are passing through argument `my $file_in = $ARGV[0];` is present in the current folder or not.

Comment: Go learn from Hameed, you guys need to calm down and find solutions instead of yip yapping all over the answer area. and run the code yourself and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script won't open file_in. `$file_in` is a variable that should be passed to the script. Note `my $file_in = $ARGV[0];`.

`$ARGV[0]` is the first command line argument that you have to pass to the script.

[How do you use command line parameters](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=33287)

If you have created a file in that directory and called it 'file_in', then run `perl_part3.pl file_in`

Comment: Shabash boi Shabadh.

Comment: That was awesome.. Take my upvote

Comment: Others didn't get it but you were on point.

Comment: Glad to have helped.